# comparing multiple columns including NAs in a dataframe R

Tags: r, dataframe, compare, multiple-columns, na

I have a dataframe include 1,2 and bunch of NAs

I would like to compare these columns and save the results in a new column (let's say F) so that:
if in each row all values are 1 then the new column get 1 for the same row
if all values are 2, then assign 2 for the same row in new column
if numbers are different (combination of 1 and 2) assign new number like 3 in the new

Do you have any idea how is it possible to doing so?

Comment: When you say *"if in each row all values are 1"* then you are not including rows that are *NA* when you say *"all"*?

Comment: Sh B, please read about how to format questions. sindri_baldur was nice enough to reformat your question previously, and your edit just wiped that improvement. It helps when the question looks consistent ("good" is subjective, of course) with code and fixed-width formatting. https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting. (In this case, highlight your data and press `Ctrl-K`.)

Comment: Please include the data you previously showed as it helps others to help you better

Comment: ... but deleting your sample data is even worse, as now others will likely vote-to-close due to lack of code and sample data.

Comment: Sorry, it is seemed my data is not shown in a right way

Comment: the columns are messed up

Answer (score 0):

Try this. If the variance is 0 then the new column equals the mean. If it is not then the new column equals the sum of the unique values (2,2,4=6). If there is only one non-NA value in a row variance will not work so the first "if" statement takes care of that.

```
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(c(1, 1, 1, NA, NA, NA, 2, 2, NA, NA, NA, NA, 3, 2, 1, 2,
                           NA, NA, 4, 2, NA, 2, NA, NA, 5, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA),
                         ncol=5, byrow=T))

colnames(df) <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "F")

for (i in 1:nrow(df)) { 
  if (length(as.numeric(df[i, 1:5])[!is.na(as.numeric(df[i, 1:5]))]) == 1) {
    df[i, "col3"] <- as.numeric(df[i, 1:5])[!is.na(as.numeric(df[i, 1:5]))]
  }
  else if (var(as.numeric(df[i, 1:5]), na.rm=T)==0) { 
    df[i, "col3"] <- mean(as.numeric(df[i, 1:5]), na.rm=T)
  } 
  else if (var(as.numeric(df[i, 1:5]), na.rm=T)!=0) {
    df[i, "col3"] <- sum(unique(as.numeric(df[i, 1:5])), na.rm=T)
  } 
}
df
```

*Updated to work for more than two columns.

Comment: Thank you so much. Is there any way to get rid of NAs first? Like replacing them with zero? Then write a code that consider just ones and twos. Actually my data is sth like this:    1 1 NA NA 2   ,  2 2 NA 1 NA ,  1 1 1 NA NA   please imagine them as a columns and rows.

Comment: I got this error after trying your code. Do you know what is that for? Error in x[[jj]][iseq] <- vjj : replacement has length zero

Comment: So you want rows with NAs to just not be evaluated? I am not sure why you would be getting that error, and will need an example of your data (I am not sure that I am understanding exactly what it looks like.

Comment: Here is an example of how you can provide us with what your data looks like. dput will return code that allows us to replicate your data.  Creating fake dataframe again`df <- data.frame(col1=c(1,2,NA,1,NA,2), col2=c(NA,1,1,1,2,NA))
df`

`dput(df)`
This is the output from dput that replicates the dataframe. `structure(list(col1 = c(1, 2, NA, 1, NA, 2), col2 = c(NA, 1, 
                                                      1, 1, 2, NA), col3 = c("1,NA", "3", "NA,1", "1", "NA,2", "2,NA"
                                                      )), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")`

Comment: Yes, exactly! i do not want NAs to be evaluated

Comment: for (i in 1:nrow(gen2)){
+ if (gen2[i,"AH1_1"] ==1 | gen2[i,"AH1_2"]==1){gen2[i,"col3"]<-1}
+ else if (gen2[i,"AH1_1"] == 2 | gen2[i,"AH1_2"]==2){gen2[i,"col3"]<-2}
+ else if (gen2[i,"AH1_1"] != gen2[i,"AH1_2"]){gen2[i,"col3"]<-gen2[i,"AH1_1"] + gen2[i,"AH1-2"]}
+ }

Comment: those are my code but again I got an error: Error in if (gen2[i, "AH1_1"] == 1 | gen2[i, "AH1_2"] == 1) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Comment: It is from NAs still being in the data frame. Are there more than two columns you are trying to evaluate?

Comment: Yes my dataframe includes five columns and 1214 rows.

Comment: If this is your data, what would your output column be? `df<-as.data.frame(matrix(c(1, 1, 1, NA, NA, NA, 2, 2, NA, NA, NA, NA, 3, 2, 1, 2, NA, NA, 4, 2, NA, 2, NA, NA, 5, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA),ncol=5, byrow = T));
colnames(df)<- c("A","B","C","D","F");
df`

Comment: my output column should be 1 if I have only ones (not any two) in my row no matter there are NAs or not. And, it should be 2 if all or at least one of them is 2 (not any one), again with or without NAs.

Comment: I updated the answer to a loop that should work better for you.

Comment: Perfect, I really appreciate it.

Comment: No problem. Feel free to mark the question as answered so others know we figured it out.

Comment: Sure, but I can not find any option to mark. Sorry I am very new member.